# What is the best way to customize populate in Strapi v4?

Tags: strapi, populate

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is this:

By default, if no "includes" query param is passed, I want to just populate everything in the model one level down, as to include all components, relations, etc. I know this is accomplished easily enough with "populate: star". However, if a field/object/array is passed in the includes, I still want the initial case of populating everything one level down (i.e. the "populate: star") but on top of it, I want to include anything passed in the query params ONLY as well. This hasn't worked for me because the second populate always overwrites the "populate: '*'". After looking thoroughly through the Strapi documentation, I don't see any way to combine these 2 scenarios so what would be the best way to accomplish something like this to dynamically handle multiple level deep populates but only for the designated relations?

Answer (score 2):

You can also predefined populate logic in middleware that populate all your items for your content.  But you can also overide via query params you would pass from the front end.

Here is an example middleware.  I am not implementing the exact logic you are looking for, but this can give you some ideas.

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * `landing-page-populate` middleware
 */

const populate = {
  metadata: {
    populate: {
      metaImage: {
        populate: true,
        fields: ["name", "alternativeText", "url"],
      },
    },
  },
  blocks: {
    populate: {
      link: {
        populate: true,
      },
      image: {
        fields: ["name", "alternativeText", "url"],
      },
      card: {
        populate: {
          image: {
            fields: ["name", "alternativeText", "url"],
          },
        },
      },
      plan: {
        populate: ["services", "link"],
      },
      form: {
        populate: ["input", "button"],
      },
    },
  },
};

module.exports = (config, { strapi }) => {
  // Add your own logic here.
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    strapi.log.info("In landing-page-populate middleware.");
    ctx.query = {
      populate,
      ...ctx.query,
    }
    await next();
  };
};
```

If you want to see another example how you can handle populate in middleware checkout this blog post. https://strapi.io/blog/route-based-middleware-to-handle-default-population-query-logic

Also you can checkout this article on populate and filtering if you need a refresher of how it is done in Strapi https://strapi.io/blog/demystifying-strapi-s-populate-and-filtering